# How to switch all lights on/off at once in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

In cycles, lights intensity can be modulated by varying their Color values.

[image]

Is there a way to do this for multiple lights at once without using individual keyframes (keying a single object is ok). My need is only to have two states (black, white) if this is more simple to obtain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use instances. (Copying with Alt + D)
Or, after the fact, assign the same Data Block to every light here:

[image: lights]

**Alternative with Drivers:**

Add a driver like this to the Strength of every lamp. That way you can maintain more control over individual lamps.

[image: driver]

This uses the zLocation of an Empty and multiplies it with the Strength. You would simply use the same Empty for all Lamps. That way you can control them all at once.

**Update for Color**

Here's an example to control the color in a similar way.

This is the node setup for the Lamp.

[image: nodes]

Then add the following drivers accordingly.

[image: hue]
[image: sat]
[image: val]

This is relatively intuitive to use.

Comment: Cool! Glad to hear! Mark as answered, if this is the solution you needed.

Comment: Note the question was for Cycles lamps which have no Strength attribute, but the principle is an interesting one. Perhaps you could update the example for the Color attribute.

Comment: Ah, you deleted your first comment. ... - The Lamp doesn't, but the Lamp Material, of course. I updated the answer to add the example for the Color. But it is basically the exact same principle.

Comment: Thanks for additional details (I didn't mean changing the color, but was asking for how was the color node changed so that the intensity of the lamp could be changed -- you actually provided the details too, great). In the meantime I learned about drivers, and see the source value for the driver could also be a custom property of one of the lamps (instead of the empty location).